# Ruby on Rails - accessing nested attributes of current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, nested-attributes

i am trying to access some nested attributes in a rails partial; let me explain my issue:

i wrote a simple messaging service according to the tutorial of dana mulder i mentioned in another question of mine. a `user` has_many `conversations`, and a `conversation` has_many `messages`. every conversation has a recipient and a sender and every message has a boolean `read`, which is set to `false` by default.

what i am trying to do is to write a simple function that iterates through every message a user got in a conversation he is involved in, checks if the last message a user recieved in a conversation is read == true and **not** send by himself to display a little knob beside the "messages" link in the navigation of my app.

What i basically want to check is (multiple lines for better readability):

```
<%= if current_user.conversations.all.messages.last.user_id != current_user.id && current_user.conversations.all.messages.last.read == false %>

    Message link with bubble beside it

<% else %>

    Message link

<% end %>
```

This syntax does not work ..
How is it possible to iterate through every conversation a user is involved, check the last message of every conversation if its written by this user and if not if its already read?

while something like `Conversation.last.messages.last.content` is working, 
`current_user.conversations.all.messages.last.content` is not.. i find it a bit confusing how the accessibility of rails models are working.

thanks in advance! i hope i was explaining me well enough.

Best Regards

Comment: Is there a separate Message link for each conversation?  Or just one for all conversations?

Comment: I guess you need to loop through each conversation. "conversations.all.messages" won't work as "conversations.all" would return an active relation object. ( On a side note using "all" should be avoided if there are many conversations. It will load all the conversations into memory causing high memory usage )

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with `current_user.conversations.all.messages.last.content`? because `conversations.all` is an association, it is NOT a Conversation, so `messages` is not an available method. `Conversation.last` IS a Conversation, that's why you can call `messages` on it.

You can try `current_user.conversations.last.messages.last.content` to get the last message of the last conversation, or, you can use a "has_many :through" relationship on User

```
class User ...
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :messages, through: :conversations
end
```

That way you can do `current_user.messages` if you want ALL user's messages and `current_user.messages.last` to get the last Message (even if it's not from the last conversation).

I'd recommend you to read the Rails Guide about Associations https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

EDIT: To know if the user has some unread message, you can use the `has_many :through` association and do something like

```
current_user.messages.where(read: false).where.not(user_id: current_user.id).any?
```

That will return `true` any message from the user's conversations with id != current_user.id is not read. And `false` otherwise.

You can use `count` instead of `any?` if you wan't to know the actual number of unread messages.

Comment: I don't think this will meet OP's intention.  If conversation 1 last message is from someone else and is unread but conversation 2 last message is from himself, he won't know there's a conversation where he hasn't seen the latest messages.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, that's why I asked what is he trying to do with the line with invalid syntax, I was just clarifying why the syntax is wrong and a few ways to fix that but it was not clear for me what was his intention

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. SteveTurczyn is right. The line with „.content“ was just to gibe an example that the one is working and the other is not. Instead ive should have wrote „.read“. I want to check if any of the messages of a conversation the current user is involved with, he is not the author of is read or not to display a hint that there is a new message. But since its in a partial im not able to access the „.read“ boolean-values easily.

Comment: @GabrielTheCoder, check my edit, with the `has_many :through` association you can query the messages to know if there's any message from a user other than current_user which is read=false.

Comment: @arieljuod that fixed a bit of the headache, thanks for this. but now i have to iterate through the messages without displaying them. ill write some more tomorrow if my brain is cleared

Comment: @GabrielTheCoder why do you say you have to iterate through all the messages? `.any?` and `.count` are just one count database query, it does not iterate over them, not sure all the context though

Comment: @arieljuod my attempt is to iterate through every message of the current user and if there is a message with `.read == false` which the user is not the author of, it should display one highlighted link, if i try `.each do`, then rails is displaying this highlighted link as often as there is a message.. can you understand me ? :S also if i use `.any?` or `.count` i cant ask rails for certain attributes like "count every message WHICH is not read yet."

Comment: @GabrielTheCoder but that's the `.where(read: false)` for, the quary already counts only messages with "read = false", and with "user_id != current_user.id" by doing `where.not(user_id: current_user.id)`. `count` applies for the whole query, it does count only unread messages

Comment: @arieljoud ye i forgot one really big point. my fault :S if a user is sending multiple messages, then only the last one seen will set to `read = true` after visiting. so the counter wont be exact and therefore trigger the "not read" highlight on the messages link. double text would break the whole mechanic. but thank you very much! that helped me, i just forgot this existed. now the only thing i have to do is to set every message that exist until now to true.

Comment: @arieljuod okay i got it to work by myself. THANK YOU for your incredible patience and help. i havent thought, that anyone would help me out with this so fast :D thank you very very much :)